# Add record with some fields manually added from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a website with `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF 6` where I want to add a record using `.Add(model)`. But I've some fields where data needs to be entered only from controller manually. I need to enter those fields manually & the rest of the fields with `.Add()`. But I'm getting Validation error since manual fields are not getting added. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FlatManagement FlatTable)
{
    FlatInfo model = FlatTable.Flat;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var getUser = db.Clients.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        FlatInfo AddFlat = new FlatInfo();
        AddFlat.admin_id = getUser.serial;
        AddFlat.user_id = 0;
        AddFlat.user_name = "N/A";
        AddFlat.user_phone = "N/A";
        db.FlatInfoes.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
     return View();
}
```

How can I add some fields manually while others will simply get added by using `.Add()` method? I don't want to add all the fields manually for just 3-4 fields since there are a lot of fields. It would be a lifesaving if someone can give me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: may be i went blind, i see you are adding model to FlatInfoes, where is it you are adding the manual fields admin_id, user_id and so on to "model"?

Comment: Shouldn't the manual fields would get added to `model` since I'm using the same object `FlatInfo()`?

Comment: you made a new object "AddFlat", all manual fields go to it. "model" is pointing to "FlatTable.Flat". aren't "AddFlat" and "FlatTable.Flat" different objects here?

Comment: "FlatTable.Flat" is `public FlatInfo Flat { get; set; }` in the "FlatManagement" model. AddFlat & FlatTable.Flat both are pointing the same object.

Comment: FlatInfo AddFlat = "new" FlatInfo() .. isn't it pointing to a "new" object. i am not sure what am i missing here. ill retire from this post !!

Comment: You create a new `FlatInfo` object using `FlatInfo AddFlat = new FlatInfo();` and set some of its properties, but you never do anything with with it. All your doing is saving the original `FlatInfo` object that you posted from the view. I suspect what you want is `model.admin_id = getUser.serial; model.user_id = 0;` etc because you saving `model`, not `AddFlat`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks a lot. Thats exactly what I was doing wrong. I wish you could give this solution earlier. But anyways, better late than never! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current method creates a new instance of `FlatInfo`

```
FlatInfo AddFlat = new FlatInfo();
```

and sets some of its properties, but then you never do anything with it. Since your saving the instance of `FlatInfo` which is a property of `FlatTable`, its that instance you need to update.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FlatManagement FlatTable)
{
    FlatInfo model = FlatTable.Flat; // this is the instance you need to update
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var getUser = db.Clients.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        model.admin_id = getUser.serial;
        model.user_id = 0;
        model.user_name = "N/A";
        model.user_phone = "N/A";
        db.FlatInfoes.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've chosen this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem you're encountering is because you're forgetting to SaveChanges after the add.

```
db.FlatInfoes.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Actually I did there. I just didn't added here. Updated my post. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the fields in the constructor of the class:

```
public class FlatInfo 
{
    public FlatInfo()
    {
        user_id=0;
        user_name = "N/A";
        user_phone = "N/A";
        // and so on    
    }   
}
```

In the controller you only have to set `AddFlat.admin_id` (which should be named `addFlat` by the way).

Comment: Will the constructor work for a `EntityFramework` generated model? And what do you mean by `(which should be named addFlat by the way)` ?

Comment: It depends. If you are using Code First, this isn't a problem. With Model First and Database First I do not know. In both latter cases you can probably add the defaults to the model or the database.

Comment: About `addFlat`. It is common practice to use camelCase for local variables.